# How do I view contents of blackberry cod file?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, project

I there any way that I can see the contents of a Blackberry COD file to check which classes are in there?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
You can unzip content of *.jar, not the *.cod.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier you could use some Zip utility like 7Zip etc to see the contents in the jad, However I got error with the cod files generated by the newer versions of the JDE

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think we can view content of BB COD file. I use [Total Commander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander) to view content of archive file, such as ZIP, JAR or COD. It's OK.

Comment: You sure that Total Commander can be used to see the contents of .cod files ??

Comment: Yes because COD is a zip file. Or you can change .COD to .ZIP and use 7zip or WinZip to view its content.

Comment: can you get the java class from COD files

Comment: i don't think one can get java files from cod files